# Contour integral of $f(z)=z$ from $z_1 = 5i$ to $z_2 = 2-2i$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to make two different contour integrals of $f(z)=z$ from $z_1 = 5i$ to $z_2 = 2-2i$. I did the first contour to be $\gamma_1 (t) = 5i + t(2-2i)$ with $0\le t \leq 1$. But my question is how can I make a second contour different from the first one I have? Is it valid to do $\gamma_2 = (2-2i) + t(5i)$ with $0\le t \leq 1$? I was trying to make a contour with a half circle but I don't really know how to make it with parameters. I get that we will have $e^{it}$ with $0 \leq t \leq \pi$ but I don't know how to include the details of $z_1$ and $z_2$. Or is it easier to make another contour with just some random point in-between $z_1$ and $z_2$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You seem to have a mistake. $\gamma_1(t)$ at $t = 1$ should be $z_2$. So it should really be $z_1 + (z_2-z_1)t, 0 \leq t \leq 1$. Check the same for $\gamma_2$.

Comment: @MathLover yes, I forgot about the subtraction. It should be $\gamma_1 = 5i + t(2-7i)$. And $\gamma_2 = (2-2i) + t(-2+7i)$, are they different contours at all? And is $5i + t^2 (2-7i)$ a different contour?

Comment: No $\gamma_2$ is not different as all points are same as $\gamma_1$. But yes taking $t^2$ will keep the endpoints same but change the contour as $t \ne t^2$ for $t \ne 0, 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can take, say, $\gamma(t)=5i+t^2(2-2i)$ ($t\in[0,1]$).